# Cakephp REST API reports missing Controller class

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to put up an RESTful API using Cakephp **3.6.2**. Following the [Official Routing Document](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#restful-routing) I received an error in JSON format as below:

```
{
    "message": "Controller class Stock could not be found.",
    "url": "/stock/index.json",
    "code": 404,
    "file": "{MY_CAKEPHP_DIRECTORY}/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ControllerFactory.php",
    "line": 105
}
```

If instead of using `/stock/index.json` but `/stock/index` will display a normal page like in the screenshot.

[Normal Stock index view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XEPh.png)

> /config/routes.php

```
<?php
Router::defaultRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);
Router::extensions(['json']);
Router::scope('/api', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->resources('Stock');
});
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
Plugin::routes();
```

> /src/Controller/StockController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Http\Exception\ForbiddenException;
use Cake\Http\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException;

class StockController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        $stock = ['test' => str_repeat('a', 11)];
        $this->set(compact('stock'));
    }
}
```

Comment: The `/api` part is missing from your request URL.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I will up-rate your comment when I have enough "reputation".